# How to save an embedding layer which was created outside model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I created a word embedding layer outside model and used it as input before fitting my model. Now I need to predict new sentences by this model, how can I save the pre-trained embedding layer and apply it to my new sentences?

Code example:

```
Before input to model and fitting:
embedding_sentence = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, model_dimension, trainable=True)
embedded_sentence = embedding_sentence(vectorized_sentence)

Model fitting:
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
...
```

Now I need to predict new sentences, how can I apply the trained embedding to them?

Answer (score 1):

The above information is insufficient to answer this question accurately but still, I will give it a try. In `tensorflow`, you can use a function named `get_weights` to get the weights of a pre-train embedding layer and save it in a `numpy/hd5` file which can be used later as an embedding layer in a new architecture.

```
weights = embedding_sentence.get_weights()
np.save('embedding_weights.npy', weights)
# Now load the weights to the embedding layer again
new_embedding_sentence = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, model_dimension, trainable=True)
new_embedding_sentence.build((None,))  # required to set the weights
new_embedding_sentence.set_weights(weights)
new_sentence = "This a dummy sentence"
new_sentence_embedding = new_embedding_sentence(new_sentence )
predictions = model(new_sentence_embedding)
```